# Matching regular expressions with R

Tags: r

I have a vector with over 300K characters that I want to compare against a much smaller 30K character vector.

The data look something like this:

```
data1 <- data.frame(col=c("Peter i.n.", "Victor Today Morgan", "Obelix", 
                          "One More"))
data2 <- data.frame(num=c(123, 434, 545, 11, 22), 
                    col=c("Victor Today", "Obelix Mobelix is.",
                          "Peter Asterix i.n.","Also","Here"))
```

Currently, I'm using the approach below, but it takes way too long to match/process it.

Would someone be so kind and suggest another approach or enhance this existing approach? Functions such as `%in%`, `merge` or `match` won't do for this purpose, because the `names to be matched` from `data1` and `data2` are not perfectly equal (that's my explanation why the functions do not match the expressions).

```
data2[as.logical(sapply(as.character(data2$col), function(x) 
  any(grepl(x, as.character(data1$col), fixed = TRUE)))),]
```

The above extracts the rows, which match with names from `data1$col`

Comment: Just to be clear, which is the smaller data set in your case? data1 or data2

Comment: How long does it take? I can't think of a better way but if you replace sapply with mclapply from package parallel for parallel processing it may help speed it up (until someone comes up with a better approach)?

Comment: Perhaps, `pmatch` is suitable and faster?

Comment: @MrFlick.The data2 is the longer version (includes all names) and the data1 just part of the names found in data2.

Comment: You can also try calling `stri_detect_fixed` from the `stringi` >=0.2 package, which can sometimes be faster (say, 2-4x) than `grepl(...fixed=TRUE)`.

Comment: @gagolews. Yeah I was looking into that package already, but could not find the right match for replacing `grelp....` I'm goinng to check it out definitelly! Thanks.

Comment: @konvas. It takes about 20 minutes. Not that long, but I'm in a need to re-use it several times...

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
col1 <- paste(data1$col, collapse = "\n")
data2[sapply(data2$col, grepl, col1, fixed = TRUE), ]
```